# Keep getting a specific error in an ML training program using tensorflow and opencv

Tags: python

In this program, I keep getting the error

```
[Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'
  File "C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\Humanoidx\data\Test 1.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils
AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer']
```

No matter what I do. What should i do now?

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils


# Configuration class for Mask R-CNN
class ObjectConfig(Config):
    # Give the configuration a unique name
    NAME = "object_detection"
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 2  # Background + Dangerous + Not Dangerous
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 100
    VALIDATION_STEPS = 20


# Dataset class for loading and preparing the training data
class ObjectDataset(utils.Dataset):
    def load_object_dataset(self, dataset_dir):
        self.add_class("object_detection", 1, "dangerous")
        self.add_class("object_detection", 2, "not dangerous")

        dangerous_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, "dangerous")
        not_dangerous_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, "not dangerous")

        dangerous_images = os.listdir(dangerous_dir)
        not_dangerous_images = os.listdir(not_dangerous_dir)

        for i, image_name in enumerate(dangerous_images):
            image_path = os.path.join(dangerous_dir, image_name)
            self.add_image("object_detection", image_id=i, path=image_path, class_id=1)

        for i, image_name in enumerate(not_dangerous_images):
            image_path = os.path.join(not_dangerous_dir, image_name)
            self.add_image("object_detection", image_id=len(dangerous_images) + i, path=image_path, class_id=2)

    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if image_info["source"] != "object_detection":
            return super().load_mask(image_id)

        class_id = image_info["class_id"]
        image_path = image_info["path"]

        # Generate mask for each object in the image
        mask = np.zeros([image_info["height"], image_info["width"], len(class_id)], dtype=np.uint8)

        # Set the pixels of the objects to 1 in the mask
        mask[:, :, class_id - 1] = 1

        # Return the mask and the class IDs as a list
        return mask.astype(np.bool), np.array(class_id, dtype=np.int32)


# Training function
def train_model(dataset_dir, weights_path):
    # Create the training and validation datasets
    dataset_train = ObjectDataset()
    dataset_train.load_object_dataset(dataset_dir)
    dataset_train.prepare()

    # Create the Mask R-CNN model in training mode
    model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training", config=ObjectConfig(), model_dir=weights_path)

    # Load the pre-trained weights (COCO or ImageNet)
    model.load_weights("path_to_pretrained_weights.h5", by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",
                                                                                 "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])

    # Train the model on the training dataset
    model.train(dataset_train, dataset_train, learning_rate=ObjectConfig().LEARNING_RATE, epochs=10, layers='all')

    # Save the weights after training
    model_path = os.path.join(weights_path, "mask_rcnn_object.h5")
    model.keras_model.save_weights(model_path)


# Call the training function with the dataset directory and desired weights path
train_model("data", "weights")
```

We are trying to use tensorflow and opencv, R-CNN and using pre-trained models to create a program that can distinguish a given image as either dangerous or safe. But we keep getting this error before wecan even train it.